# How do I create frames of different colours in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to create frames with a gradient colour change from black to white.For instance first frame should be black(0,0,0), then (50,0,0), then (50,50,0).....so on all the way to (255,255,255). But im only able to produce a single frame (0,0,0) with this code. Also is it possible to create a sequentially numbered jpg file for each image?

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    def create_blank(width, height, rgb_color=(0, 0, 0)):
    """Create new image(numpy array) filled with certain color in RGB"""
    # Create black blank image
        image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

    # Since OpenCV uses BGR, convert the color first
        color = tuple(reversed(rgb_color))
    # Fill image with color
        image[:] = color
        return image


    for i in range(0,50,255):
        for j in range(0,50,255):
            for k in range(0,50,255):
                image=create_blank(width, height, rgb_color=(i,j,k))
                cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',image)
```

Comment: Your `range` call is wrong. Use `range(0, 255, 50)` if you want to have something like `0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250`. It's `range(start, stop, step)`. Attention: `255` is not included!! Also, if you don't want to overwrite your image everytime, add `i, j, k` to your filename, maybe like so: `cv2.imwrite('img_{}_{}_{}.jpg'.format(i, j, k), image)`. (Attention: That'll be 216 images...)

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def create_gradient(width, height):
    image = np.zeros((1,width,3), dtype='uint8') # starting image with one row black pixels
    for row in range(height): 
        pixel_value = int(row*255/height)
        new_row = np.ones((1,width,3), dtype='uint8')*pixel_value # creating new row 
        image = np.concatenate((image, new_row)) # concatenate images
    return image

img = create_gradient(200,500)
cv2.imshow('gradient', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you want switch from vertical to horizontal just swap heigh with width.
To save images sequentialy you should add `cv2.imwrite` in for loop.

Return from code above looks like this:

[image]